# Same parameters lead to very different results

Tags: ultimaker-cura, pla, filament, dremel-3d45

This summer I bought a white PLA+ filament from [Sunlu](https://www.amazon.it/SUNLU-Filamento-Stampante-Tangle-Bianco/dp/B07R8X76GW).
After some trials, I found these settings in Ultimaker Cura for my Dremel 3D45:

[image]

The layer thickness is 0.2 mm.
The objects were printed almost perfectly for my needs:

[image]

Now, after 3 months, I tried to print with the same material and of course with the same parameters. Even if the infill seems quite good:

[image]

the walls are terrible:

[image]

I'm using a dryer before and during the printing.
I'm lost because I cannot think what can be happened.

The other variable is the environment temperature in the box: this summer was about 20 °C, now it is 12-13 °C. But given the use of the dryer and given that the Dremel is closed it should not matter.

Could the filament be damaged?
Any other idea?

Comment: Are you printing in heated enclosure?

Comment: @kosteklvp, not sure what you mean. The Dremel 3D45 has the buildplate enclosed. The chamber itself is not "heated", but of course all the heating sources (nozzle, bed) are inside.

Comment: So the enclosure is not heated. My guess is a temperature problem. You said, that you have different temperature now inside. Maybe try printing with different temperature and decrease cooling. It is now colder, so cooling can be the problem here.

Comment: Please try with new PLA, once moisture has crept in, the filament changes, this cannot be undone by drying it.

Comment: @kosteklvp good advice. I'm going to try it this morning.

Comment: @0scar this is new to me. So, what's the purpose of the driers?

Comment: I use the dryer for PETG and that works, it is known that the large PLA molecules break up due to the moisture (there is an SE question to be found on that), so even when dried, the filament has a different structure. It is best to never let it get wet. So pack it well and print from a drier or a box.

Comment: I dispute that water degrades PLAs in general, but some filaments contain fillers that break with water. See scientific experiments by CNC Kitchen https://youtu.be/FAXUjZZER5E

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem?

Comment: @kosteklvp unfortunately not yet. I also received a new bobbin of the very same filament but the behavior is not changed at all.

Comment: This "bobbin" sounds like a dry filament. Wet filament can also lead to adhesion problems. Maybe you didn't dry your filament enough.

Next, you should determine the best temperature for now. Try printing temperature tower for optimum temperature and cooling. You said that the environment temperature is now 12°C, so your cooling may be stronger now, which can lead to adhesion and curling issues.

Comment: Have you tried printing with different filament?

Comment: @kosteklvp no problem with other filaments. Anyway, the humidity should not matter anymore, since I've ordered a new item of the same filament.

Comment: So try playing with printing temperature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a clogged nozzle.

Clean your nozzle, and if you have a setup with a Bowden tube coming up to the nozzle, like an Ender 3, check that it is clean, and has good, strong contact with the nozzle.

The low ambient temperature is not helping, but should create warping, not a total lack of material.

In addition, make sure that you have a silicone sock on your heat block to protect from too much heat loss and have a more even temperature.